# So i have 3 products on my db but on my local machine i see 9...somehow every time i create a product it is duplicating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Product Load (4.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
>   => #http://www.heritagedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/20...", created_at:
>   "2017-03-07 19:17:57", updated_at: "2017-03-07 19:17:57", colour:
>   "brown", price: #>,
>
> "http://www.heritagedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/20...", created_at:
>   "2017-03-07 19:17:57", updated_at: "2017-03-07 19:17:57", colour:
>   "brown", price: #>,
>
> "http://www.heritagedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/20...", created_at:
>   "2017-03-07 19:17:57", updated_at: "2017-03-07 19:17:57", colour:
>   "brown", price: #>

And this is what i get on my localhost once i go to the product page =>

> ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT
>   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations" Processing by
>   StaticPagesController#landing_page as HTML   Rendering
>   static_pages/landing_page.html.erb within layouts/application
>   DEPRECATION WARNING: uniq is deprecated and will be removed from Rails
>   5.1 (use distinct instead) (called from
>   _app_views_static_pages_landing_page_html_erb__3481566516998456644_70117399973400
>   at
>   /Users/jovanka/Desktop/the_antique/app/views/static_pages/landing_page.html.erb:23)
>   Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "products".* FROM "products"
>   Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY
>   "products"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]   Rendered
>   static_pages/landing_page.html.erb within layouts/application (20.5ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 428ms (Views: 404.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
>
> Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:33 -0600 Started GET
>   "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:33 -0600
>   Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET,
>   HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) An unauthorized
>   connection attempt was rejected Failed to upgrade to WebSocket
>   (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE:
>   websocket) Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07
>   14:23:33 -0600 Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07
>   14:23:33 -0600 Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:42
>   -0600 Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:42 -0600 Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) An unauthorized
>   connection attempt was rejected Failed to upgrade to WebSocket
>   (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE:
>   websocket) Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07
>   14:23:42 -0600 Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07
>   14:23:42 -0600 Started GET "/products" for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:43
>   -0600 Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML   Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application   Product Load
>   (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" Product: Ancient
>   Jewellery  Product: Ancient Jewellery  Product: Ancient Jewellery
>   Rendered products/_product.html.erb (7.9ms) Product: Ancient Jewellery
>   Product: Ancient Jewellery  Product: Ancient Jewellery    Rendered
>   products/_product.html.erb (2.2ms) Product: Ancient Jewellery 
>   Product: Ancient Jewellery  Product: Ancient Jewellery    Rendered
>   products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)   Rendered products/index.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (20.9ms) Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views:
>   142.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
>
> Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:43 -0600 Started GET
>   "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:43 -0600
>   Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET,
>   HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) An unauthorized
>   connection attempt was rejected Failed to upgrade to WebSocket
>   (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE:
>   websocket) Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07
>   14:23:43 -0600 Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07
>   14:23:43 -0600 Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:53
>   -0600   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations" Started GET "/cable/"
>   [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:53 -0600 Successfully upgraded
>   to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade,
>   HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) An unauthorized connection attempt was
>   rejected Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET,
>   HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) Finished "/cable/"
>   [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:53 -0600 Finished "/cable/"
>   [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:23:53 -0600 Started GET "/cable"
>   for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:24:05 -0600 Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket]
>   for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:24:05 -0600 Successfully upgraded to
>   WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade,
>   HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) An unauthorized connection attempt was
>   rejected Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET,
>   HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) Finished "/cable/"
>   [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:24:05 -0600 Finished "/cable/"
>   [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-03-07 14:24:05 -0600

products/_product.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |product| %> 
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4"> 
    <h3><%= link_to product.name, product %></h3> 
    <% if product.image_url.present? %> 
      <%= image_tag(product.image_url , class: "img-thumbnail") %> 
    <% end %>
    <br> <strong>Description<%= product.description %></strong> <br/>
    <strong>Colour:<%= product.colour %></strong> <br/> 
    <strong>Price: $ <%= product.price %></strong> <br/> 
    <%= link_to 'Show', product ,class:"btn btn-default"%> 
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product), class:"btn btn-default" %> 
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class:"btn btn-default"%> 
    <% logger.debug "Product: #{product.name}"%> <br> <br> 
  </div> <!-- /col --> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please show your `products/_product.html.erb`

Comment: <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4">
      <h3><%= link_to product.name, product %></h3>


      <% if product.image_url.present? %>
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url , class: "img-thumbnail") %>
      <% end %>

Comment: <br>
      <strong>Description<%= product.description %></strong>
      <br/>
      <strong>Colour:<%= product.colour %></strong>
      <br/>

      <strong>Price: $ <%= product.price %></strong>
      <br/>

      <%= link_to 'Show', product ,class:"btn btn-default"%>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product), class:"btn btn-default" %>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class:"btn btn-default"%>
      <% logger.debug "Product: #{product.name}"%>
      <br>
      <br>
     </div> <!-- /col -->
<% end %>

Comment: @Iceman can you see

Comment: @Jovanka, it is better if you update your original post with the code.
Also, please include the code of the controller, where the variable products is being created.

Comment: @Jovanka, we still need the code for the ProductController, or whichever action that populates "@products"

Comment: It is the first time i am posting something so i have no idea what i am doing @fabriciofreitag seems like i am not able to post the code and i dont know why

Comment: @fabriciofreitag i hope it helps ... i was not able to copy the controller file i don't know why

Comment: @Jovanka I'm installing your project here to see if I can simulate the issue

Comment: not a problem thanks @fabriciofreitag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem looking into [the source](https://github.com/JovankaN/my_app/blob/master) you provided.
You were looping through the products two times.
The first time in the ./app/views/products/index.html.erb and then again in ./app/views/products/_product.html.erb.
The solution would be to remove the loop from outside the partial as such:

/app/views/products/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <%= render partial: "product" %>
  </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

Comment: you are amazing  this is great ... Thanks live saver